# How to remove one extension by asterisk CLI

Tags: asterisk

How to remove one extension by asterisk `CLI`?

I try the command:

```
remove extension 300809@from-internal
```

return

```
failed to remove extension 300809@from-internal
```

The extension existed , I could use the command to show it :

```
sip show user   300809
```

return

```
* Name       : 300809


Secret       : <Set>
  MD5Secret    : <Not set>
  Context      : from-internal
  Language     : 
  AMA flags    : Unknown
  CallingPres  : Presentation Allowed, Not Screened
  Call limit   : 0
  Callgroup    : 
  Pickupgroup  : 
  Callerid     : "device" <300809>
  ACL          : No
  Codec Order  : (ulaw|alaw)
```

Answer (score -1):

`300809@from-internal` is not an extension. most likely it is the user id.

At least in asterisk terminology an extension would be in the dialplan it would look like this `[some_extension]`. the filename is:

```
/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf
```

Comment: Thanks ，I could not find the 300809 in /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf. The '300809' is added in http://X.X.X.X/admin/config.php?type=setup&display=extensions and select  Generic sip  Device to create the extension. Now I only want to delete the extension. Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: there is no such commands, just edit the config file directly